# remote actor work only on localhost

Tags: scala, actor

I wrote a program using Scala's remote actors. My first step was to create a client and a server who communicate by loopback (127.0.0.1) and it works well. When I try to communicate between two stations on the same network, the server doesn't catch anything. The only thing I changed between local and remote client's program is the server's IP address.

Here is the client code:

```
case class Post(msg: String)

object Client extends Application {
  val client = new ClientRemote
  client.sendMessage
}

class ClientRemote extends Actor {
  val server = select(Node("127.0.0.1", 9010), 'name) //' or server IP

  def sendMessage(): Unit = {
    server ! Post("Hello!")
  }

  def act() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Here is the server code:

```
case class Post(msg: String)

object Server extends Application {
  val server = new ServerRemote
  server.start
}

class ServerRemote extends Actor {
  def act() {
    alive(9010)
    println("server is started!")
    register('name, self)                  //' register to port
    loop {
      react {
        case Post(msg) => println(msg)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know why these programs dont' work or any idea about a solution?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know more about Java than I do Scala, but is it possible that your duplicate definitions of the Post case class are considered different classes by the class-loader?

Answer (score 0):

You can add "scala.actors.Debug.level = 3" at the beginning of the client and server code to get more information about what the actor sub-system is doing. This will tell you, for example, if the message was received but dropped, or if its listening on a different port than you thought, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's very helpfull. 

The error is : caught java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.actors.remote.Node; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -4252948855987918585, local class serialVersionUID = -7525549079045563153

I think this is a serialization problem.

Comment: I think that would point to what Unami stated in another answer. The class Post is defined separately twice, so each version gets its own UID.  Instead, define Post once and included that class file with both the server and the client.